# react testing function with asynchronous setState call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, testing, mocha.js

I have the following function in my React component

```
changeProject(project) {
    const buildProjectValues = [];
    BambooService.GetBuilds(project).then((res) => {
      res.map(build => {
        buildProjectValues.push({'label':build.searchEntity.planName, 'value':build.searchEntity.id});
      });
      this.setState({buildValues:buildProjectValues})
    })
  }
```

With an associated test:

```
it('should set buildValues state property to returned array from API call', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<RepoForm projectValues={projectOptions} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    nock('https://myurl.api.com')
      .get('/builds?projectKey=KEY')
      .reply(200, buildMock)

    instance.changeProject('KEY');
    expect(instance.state.buildValues).to.equal(buildMock);
  })
```

The problem is my test completes, as a failure, before the promise in my code resolves, as well as setState being asynchronous anyway!

I've tried using setImmediate as follows, but the same outcome happens;

```
it('should set buildValues state property to returned array from API call', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<RepoForm projectValues={projectOptions} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    nock('https://myurl.api.com')
      .get('/builds?projectKey=KEY')
      .reply(200, buildMock)

    instance.changeProject('KEY');
    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(instance.state.buildValues).to.equal(buildMock);
    });

  })
```

Is there some way I could rewrite my code to avoid this?  Or is there some other pattern out there I could use for this scenario for testing my async code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First edit changeProject() to return the promise to use it in your test:

```
changeProject(project) {
    const buildProjectValues = [];
    return BambooService.GetBuilds(project).then((res) => {
      res.map(build => {
        buildProjectValues.push({
           'label':build.searchEntity.planName,
           'value':build.searchEntity.id
        });
      });
      this.setState({buildValues:buildProjectValues})
    })
  }
```

Then in the test, add put your assertion in `then()`:

```
it('should set buildValues state property to returned array from API call', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<RepoForm projectValues={projectOptions} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    nock('https://myurl.api.com')
      .get('/builds?projectKey=KEY')
      .reply(200, buildMock)

    instance.changeProject('KEY')
       .then(() => {
            expect(instance.state.buildValues).to.equal(buildMock);
       });    
  })
```

You can also use `await` instead of `then()`

```
await instance.changeProject('KEY');     
expect(instance.state.buildValues).to.equal(buildMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `changeProject()` to return the promise:

```
changeProject(project) {
    const buildProjectValues = [];
    return BambooService.GetBuilds(project).then((res) => {
      res.map(build => {
        buildProjectValues.push({'label':build.searchEntity.planName, 'value':build.searchEntity.id});
      });
      this.setState({buildValues:buildProjectValues})
    })
}
```

Now you can get the promise in your test and allow Jest to resolve it before you call `expect()`:

```
it('should set buildValues state property to returned array from API call', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<RepoForm projectValues={projectOptions} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    nock('https://myurl.api.com')
      .get('/builds?projectKey=KEY')
      .reply(200, buildMock)

    return instance.changeProject('KEY')
        .then(() => {
          expect(instance.state.buildValues).to.equal(buildMock);
        });
})
```

When you return a promise from a Jest test, Jest will attempt to resolve it. The `then()` will be called if the promise is successfully resolved.